# how to make closing animation for popup WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, popup

I can use PopupAnimation property like Fade.(PopupAnimation="Fade")
but I can't use fade-out animation. 
I want to make animation when popup open and close.

Comment: Did you set AllowsTransparency="True"

Comment: You can Animate the Opacity.